# Is there a way to check logs about user login?

Tags: compiz, login

The login process to my Ubuntu box takes a long time, maybe a minute or longer.

Unlike the bootstrap which prints a lot of messages to the console, there is nothing displayed when GUI started.

I've checked `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.1.log`, most of them are a bit of lower level information about display devices, seem like things happened before the login, and nothing related to startup applications.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When is it slow?  Before you see the login screen or between entering your password and getting to a usable desktop?

If before, [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) may help.

If after, you should also have a look in the file `.xsession-errors` for any errors.

And try disabling programs via `System->Preferences->Startup Applications` and log out and in each time, until you see which one makes a big difference.

Another option is the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/).  Before logging in, switch to a virtual console (e.g. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), then log in, and run `auditctl` to make it record every process starting and finishing.  Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the graphical login screen, log in, then run `aureport` to print the information out.

You may also be able to put `strace -e trace=process > /tmp/startup.log 2>&1` into your startup configuration files somewhere, e.g. edit `/etc/gdm/Xsession` and change `eval exec $command` to `eval exec strace -e trace=process $command >/tmp/startup.log 2>&1`.  Whether `Xsession` is the right place will depend on when the slowness is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bootchart, which looks to be in the repositories, gnome-system-log is very useful for checking all your system logs.